# How to fix paint artifacts when replacing items in Tree View?

Tags: winapi, treeview, comctl32

I have a Tree View positioned in the content area of a Tab Control (the Tree View is a sibling of the Tab Control). When I remove tree view items, add new tree view items, and select one of them, the tree view is not painted correctly; everything above the newly created+selected item is gray. Is there any way to make the tree view paint everything properly after removing and inserting items?

[image: Before replacing items]
[image: After replacing items]

Observations:

- If there are few enough tree view items that no scroll bar appears, then the tree view looks OK.
- If there is no tab control adjacent to the tree view, then the tree view looks OK.
- If the tree view is a child of the tab control, then the tree view looks OK (but the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key can’t navigate between the Tab Control and the Tree View using GetNextDlgTabItem/IsDialogMessage).
- If I don’t select any items in the Tree View after inserting new nodes, then the tree view looks OK.

When I insert items into the tree, I call TreeView_InsertItem followed by TreeView_SelectItem. [Full sample gist](https://gist.github.com/yonran/8c7f187a2ade8aba7f5f). In the sample program, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> accelerator replaces all the tree nodes and causes the artifacts.

Comment: Try setting WS_CLIPSIBLINGS / WS_CLIPCHILDREN on the tab control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error here:

```
ACCEL accel[1]***; //change to accel[2]
accel[0].fVirt = FCONTROL | FVIRTKEY;
accel[0].key = 'R';
accel[0].cmd = IDM_REGENERATETREE;
accel[1].fVirt = FCONTROL | FVIRTKEY;
accel[1].key = 'S';
accel[1].cmd = IDM_SELECTRANDOM;
HACCEL haccel = CreateAcceleratorTable(accel, 2);
```

Display problems are caused when trying to save previous item state. There are no display problems if you remove `previousStates` from `addTreeItem`. To save the state properly you may need std::map and some user identification for each tree item. At least you should use std::vector to make it easier to follow.

For better visual effects you can add `TVS_LINESATROOT` to TreeView and `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to main window.

Edit:

Saving previous item states shouldn't be done in `addTreeItem`. For example new item that was just inserted won't have children yet, so it can't be expanded. Simplify `addTreeItem` as follows:

```
HTREEITEM addTreeItem(HWND htree, HTREEITEM par, HTREEITEM after, LPCTSTR str, LPARAM lp) 
{
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins;
    tvins.hParent = par;
    tvins.hInsertAfter = after;
    tvins.itemex.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
    tvins.itemex.pszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>(str);
    tvins.itemex.lParam = lp;
    HTREEITEM node = TreeView_InsertItem(htree, &tvins);
    return node; 
}
```

To save previous item state, each item should have a different ID. As it happens in this example item's name is different for each node, we can use that for map. But if this was a directory structure it wouldn't work, we have to use fullpath instead of node name.

```
void RootWindow::RegenerateTree()
{
    if (!m_hwndTreeView) return;
    if (!IsWindow(m_hwndTreeView)) return;
    HWND hwnd = m_hwndTreeView;

    //this will stop treeview from updating after every insert
    SetWindowRedraw(hwnd, 0);

    std::map<std::wstring, UINT> state;
    const int maxtext = 260;
    wchar_t buf[maxtext];
    std::wstring selection;

    UINT count = TreeView_GetCount(hwnd);
    if (count)
    {
        for (HTREEITEM item = TreeView_GetRoot(hwnd); item; item = nextItem(hwnd, item))
        {
            TVITEM tv{ 0 };
            tv.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_STATE;
            tv.stateMask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_STATE;
            tv.cchTextMax = maxtext;
            tv.pszText = buf;
            tv.hItem = item;
            if (TreeView_GetItem(hwnd, &tv))
                state[buf] = TreeView_GetItemState(hwnd, item, 
                TVIS_SELECTED | TVIS_EXPANDED);
        }
    }
    TreeView_DeleteAllItems(hwnd);

    addTreeItem...
    addTreeItem...
    addTreeItem...

    //restore previous item state here:
    if (count)
    {
        for (HTREEITEM item = TreeView_GetRoot(hwnd); item; item = nextItem(hwnd, item))
        {
            TVITEM tvitem{ 0 };
            tvitem.hItem = item;
            tvitem.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
            tvitem.cchTextMax = maxtext;
            tvitem.pszText = buf;
            if (TreeView_GetItem(hwnd, &tvitem))
                TreeView_SetItemState(hwnd, item, state[buf], 
                TVIS_SELECTED | TVIS_EXPANDED);
        }
    }

    SetWindowRedraw(hwnd, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding WS_CLIPCHILDREN to the top-level window, adding WS_CLIPSIBLINGS to the Tab Control, and calling SetWindowPos to move the Tree View on top of the Tab Control in z-order eliminated the gray regions. Now the only problem is that the buttons at the root level disappear when I recreate the tree.

Comment: That only fixes minor flicker. Even if you remove the tab control the problem remains. The main problem is with `previousStates ` in `addTreeItem`, that's why items disappear.

Comment: I have now revised the example to use a std::map instead of a LocalAlloc’d block.

Comment: You are not using `LPARAM` here, or maybe you intend to use it later. I changed it to `std::map<std::wstring, UINT>` for now.

Comment: Actually I am using `LPARAM` as a unique node ID in this sample. But thank you for all the help! I no longer set TVIS_EXPANDED while creating the tree item; I wait until I have added the children. I call `TreeView_Expand` and `TreeView_SelectItem` instead of setting `TVIS_EXPANDED | TVIS_SELECTED` state. The drawing artifacts are now gone. And to reduce flicker I use `SetWindowRedraw`.

Comment: Yes that should work nicely. You can also use `TreeView_EnsureVisible` at the very end, once, to make sure selection is not scrolled out of view.